# Problema para enviar e-mail com mailtrap usando Docker(MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, email, docker

Estou estudando o desenvolvimento de uma API e estou com problemas de usar o mailtrap para fazer o teste de enviar e-mail durante a validação de usuário.
O usuário é escrito no mongo porém ele não manda o email e retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
```

Entendi que isso era um erro de porta e fui atrás de respostas, achei uma solução criando um arquivo chamado daemon.json dentro da pasta /etc/docker  com o seguinte conteudo de DNS:

```
    { "dns": ["89.101.160.5", "89.101.160.4"] }
```

O problema persistiu no Ubuntu.
Mudei de máquina e no mac com outra conta do Docker, outro container o erro persiste.

Alguém sabe uma saída?

Comment: Já testou o transporter fora do ambiente docker? Eu tive um problema com a sdk da aws em ambiente dev, só descobri o problema testando ele separadamente.

Comment: Você fala testar com um mongodb local? Ainda não, vou testar e reporto aqui.

Comment: Não exatamente, mas também, digo testar o método de envio de emails fora do ambiente docker ou até criar um metodo apenas para envio do email por exemplo. [Exemplo](https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/email-jpg-ca8c7707-da6f-4d74-b020-17d81595a842)